# dependency injection in Angular when extending a class

Tags: angular

I am a Java guy learning Angular.
I have a service and I would like to have injected that service into my object. This [doc](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) explains well how to do it in a normal case. As I understand the concept, in the example we use constructor dependency injection.

But in my case, this is not possible because I am extending a class that has its own constructor with 3 parameters and I am not allowed to modify the parent constructor. So I can not add a 4th parameter to my constructor to have injected the service.

This code does not work because the last constructor param is invalid.

**my code:**

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {

  constructor(readonly service1: Service1,
              readonly service2: Service2,
              el?: ElementRef | null,
              readonly service3: Service3) { <-- invalid param
    super(service1, service2, el);
  }
```

What is the alternative dependency injection if the constructor injection is not an option?

Comment: You define the constructor for each component itself, independent of the extended class. So, you should be able to inject `service3` into the constructor of `ChildComponent`. Try change `readonly` to `private` for `service3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting the service through the constructor, you can declare a property in your child component and annotate it with the @Inject decorator to specify the service you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [inject](https://angular.io/api/core/inject) function to retrieve your injectable without having to add as a constructor's parameter (you will do what angular is doing internally):

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  private myService: Service3;

  constructor(
    readonly service1: Service1,
    readonly service2: Service2,
    el?: ElementRef | null
  ) {
    super(service1, service2, el);
    this.myService = inject(Service3);
  }
}
```

Note that you can also inject like that:

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  private myService = inject(Service3);

  constructor(
    readonly service1: Service1,
    readonly service2: Service2,
    el?: ElementRef | null
  ) {
    super(service1, service2, el);
  }
}
```